# Von Neumann entropy identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, information, entanglement-entropy

Can someone prove that for an ensamble $\epsilon=\{p_{i}, \rho_{i} \}$ it is true that

$$
H(p) \geq S(\rho)-\sum_{i}p_{i}S(\rho_{i})
$$

where $H(p)=\sum_{i}p_{i}log(1/p_{i})$ and $\rho=\sum_{i}p_{i}\rho_{i}$.

It can be used that
$$
S\left( \sum_{i}p_{i}\rho_{i}\right)\geq\sum_{i}p_{i}S(\rho_{i}).
$$